# Batch updating Updating over 200000 rows in a table using psycopg2

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Hi I am trying to update over 200000 rows (exact : 273649).

I wrote the following code to update:

```
with open('gene.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
            sql = "UPDATE sequence_group_annotation SET STATUS = '" + row['status'] + "', UPDATED_DATE=CURRENT_DATE where seq_id_pk='" + row['ensembl_gene_id'] + "'"
            print sql
            cur.execute(sql);
```

At the print sql statement, I am redirecting my file :

```
update.py > results.txt
```

Ideally this should update the table, but it is not doing so.

To check, what I did was the following :

```
select seq_id_pk,status from sequence_group_annotation where status ISNULL and TYPE <> 3
```

and looked for for the corresponding seq_id_pk in my results.txt file

I copied the sql statement and ran it. I was able to successfully update it after that.

Any idea on why this is not working?

Comment: I can off course, execute all the commands through pgsql, but I am looking for a way to do it through psycopg2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `commit()` your changes. psycopg begins an implicit transaction for you on the first `execute()` and you need to `commit()` or `rollback()` on the `connection` object at the end.